# Unable to render the CSS data in GrapeJS editor angular node frame work

Tags: sql, node.js, angular

I have integrated the https://grapesjs.com  grapejs editor in angular template, and implemented the lode and store APIs to store the templates with the id.
The store API stores the HTML and CSS data of the template in db so now the issue I am facing is, when i load the template with stored html and CSS data, the html data rendering properly CSS is not rendering, and when i give CSS data dynamically to the obj it is rendering properly. please help me in this. Thank you!!

in landing page object i have commented the dynamic code that works fine.

```
import { TemplateService } from '../template.service';
import grapesjs from 'grapesjs';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import 'grapesjs-preset-webpage';
import { extendsDirectlyFromObject } from '@angular/core/src/render3/jit/directive';
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grape',
  templateUrl: './grape.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grape.component.css']
})
export class GrapeComponent implements OnInit {
  private _editor: any;

  LandingPage :any= {
    html: null,
    css: null,
    components: null,
    style: null,
    assets: null
  };
  page:any;
  constructor(private templateService: TemplateService) { }

  get editor() {
    return this._editor;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.coretemplate();
  }
  coretemplate() {
    this._editor = this.initializeEditor();
    this.editor.Panels.addButton
      ('options',
        [{
          id: 'save-db',
          className: 'fa fa-floppy-o',
          command: 'save-db',
          attributes: { title: 'Save DB' },
        }, {
          id: 'get-db',
          className: 'fa fa-upload',
          command: 'get-db',
          attributes: { title: 'get DB' },
          type: {}
        }]
      );
    this.template();
  }
  template() {
    let fileName: any;
    let fileId: any;
    // Add the command
    this.editor.Commands.add
      ('save-db', {
        run: (editor, sender) => {
          fileName = prompt('Please enter a file name to save!');
          sender && sender.set('active'); // turn off the button
          editor.store();
        }
      });
    this.editor.Commands.add
      ('get-db', {
        run: (editor, sender) => {
          sender && sender.set('active');
          fileId = prompt('please enter ID to open');
          console.log("file ID", fileId);
          this.templateService.getAPIData(fileId)
            .subscribe((Response) => {
              let resData = Response["rows"];
              let rowsJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resData[0]));
               var cssData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rowsJson["CSS"]));
              this.LandingPage = {
                // html:`<div class=\"lala-row\"><div class=\"lala-cell\"></div><div class=\"lala-cell\"><div class=\"lala-row\"><div class=\"lala-cell\"></div><div class=\"lala-cell\"><div id=\"ilm16\">welcome to template</div></div></div></div></div><div id=\"i8mz\">template</div>`,
                //  css:  "* { box-sizing: border-box; } body {margin: 0;}#ilm16{padding:10px;}#i8mz{padding:10px;background-color:#b72525;}.lala-row{display:table;padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;width:100%;}.lala-cell{width:8%;display:table-cell;height:75px;}@media (max-width: 768px){.lala-cell{width:100%;display:block;}}",
               html: rowsJson["HTML"],
               css:cssData.toString(),
                components: null,
                style: null,
                assets: null
              };
              this.coretemplate();
              console.log("Landing Page=>", this.LandingPage);
            });
        }
      });
    this.editor.on('storage:store', (e) => {
      var jsonseHtml = JSON.stringify(e.html);
      var jsonseCss = JSON.stringify(e.css);
      var jsonseAssets = JSON.stringify(e.assets);
      var jsonseStyles = JSON.stringify(e.styles);
      var jsonseComponents = JSON.stringify(e.components);
      console.log("CSS=>", jsonseCss);
      this.templateService.saveData(fileName, jsonseHtml, jsonseCss, jsonseAssets, jsonseStyles).subscribe((Response) => {
        alert("Template Saved!!!");
        console.log(Response);
      }, (error) => {
        alert("Error While Saving!!!")
        console.log(error);
      });
    });
  }

  private initializeEditor(): any {
    console.dir(window);
    return grapesjs.init({
      container: '#gjs',
      autorender: true,
      forceClass: false,
      // components:'',
      components: this.LandingPage.html,
      style: this.LandingPage.css,
      //style: '',
      plugins: ['gjs-preset-webpage'],
      pluginsOpts: {
        'gjs-preset-webpage': {
          navbarOpts: false,
          countdownOpts: false,
          formsOpts: false,
          blocksBasicOpts: {
            blocks: ['link-block', 'quote', 'image', 'video', 'text', 'column1', 'column2', 'column3'],
            flexGrid: false,
            stylePrefix: 'lala-'
          }
        }
      },
      storageManager: {
        autosave: false,
        setStepsBeforeSave: 1,
        //make it true for auto load
        autoload: false,
        //  type: 'remote',
        //  urlStore: 'http://localhost:3000/templateSave'+name,
        //  urlLoad: 'http://localhost:3000/getPath/'+this.TEMPID,
        type: 'local',
        urlStore: '',
        urlLoad: '',
        contentTypeJson: true,
      },
      assetManager: {
        uploadText: 'Add image through link or upload image',
        modalTitle: 'Select Image',
        openAssetsOnDrop: 1,
        inputPlaceholder: '',
        addBtnText: 'Add image',
        uploadFile: (e) => {
          const file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.target.files[0];
          console.log("file =====>", file);
        },
        handleAdd: (textFromInput) => {
          this.editor.AssetManager.add(textFromInput);
        }
      },
      canvas: {
        styles: [
          'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css',
          'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'
        ],
        scripts: ['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js']
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi @artf can you check and help me?

Comment: from the description you give, it seems that you get the data from some sort of observable wich is not triggered when the data is static.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to use the `setStyle` function? It should add a CSS pro you on the body.... 
https://grapesjs.com/docs/api/editor.html#setstyle

Worst case scenario, you can add a link on the Canvas.styles for the CSS that you are trying to load...